# Training a convnet, the training accuracy does not go beyond 80%. Is it a labeling problem?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm training a convnet for classification. While training, all appears to run smoothly except for no matter the training size the final training accuracy is limited to about 80%. 
I'm guessing there must be labeling noise in my dataset. ( The goal is not merely cats and dogs, it's defining pathological regions that have certain subjectivity embedded in them.)
The question is, can upper limited training accuracy be an indication of labeling noise?

Comment: What is the prevalence of your classes? And how were they labeled in the first place?

Comment: Roughly 50-50. They were labelled by a pathologist.

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like a good start. When you say “final training accuracy” you mean prediction on a held-out dataset not used for training? And by “accuracy” do you mean _accuracy_ or something like precision and recall? Last, what’s your architecture and your input/output?

Comment: No. I mean the accuracy on the training set itself. The validation accuracy is of course lower. The major point of the question is why the training accuracy won't reach 100%. The structure is convnet and max pooling cascades with a fully connected network for classification.